# Grouping by two values and calculating the third one

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that contains results of some benchmarking tests. The class looks more or less like this:

```
public class TestResult
{
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public int SampleSize { get; set; }
    public double Result { get; set; }
}
```

I have ran all tests many times, so I have many results for each sample size, like:

```
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 1024, Result: 2.4741
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 1024, Result: 2.5029
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 1024, Result: 2.4902
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 2048, Result: 4.5654
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 2048, Result: 4.7156
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 2048, Result: 4.2238
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 4096, Result: 10.1863
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 4096, Result: 9.9471
TestName: "MemoryTest", SampleSize: 4096, Result: 10.2240

TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 1024, Result: 2.4741
TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 1024, Result: 2.5029
TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 1024, Result: 2.4902
TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 2048, Result: 4.5654
TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 2048, Result: 4.7156
TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 2048, Result: 4.2238
TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 4096, Result: 10.1863
TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 4096, Result: 9.9471
TestName: "GraphicsTest", SampleSize: 4096, Result: 10.2240
```

Now I would like to create a List containing the average of all the results, but grouped by both TestName and SampleSize.

Looking on an example above, I'd like to have a list containing 6 result : 3 for GraphicsTest and 3 for MemoryTest, with averages for each SampleSize.

I have trouble grouping by two different columns. I've tried it for a few ways, but I can't get a grasp on it...

My best approach so far is:

```
        var _Consolidation =
            from _R in Results
            group _R by new { _R.TestName, _R.SampleSize } into _G
            select new TestResult()
            {
                TestName = _G.Key.TestName,
                SampleSize = _G.Key.SampleSize,
                Result = from _Res 
                         in Results
                         where _Res.TestName == _G.Key.TestName && _Res.SampleSize == _G.Key.SampleSize
                         select _X => new
                         {
                             // ? Average Result? How to calculate it?
                         }
            };
```

But I'm not sure if I'm going the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you need to group by an anonymous type, which you have, then averaging the grouping is simply an average against the collection of the group:

```
var query = items
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.TestName, x.SampleSize})
    .Select(x => new TestResult 
    {
        TestName = x.Key.TestName,
        SampleSize = x.Key.SampleSize,
        Result = x.Average(y => y.Result)
    });
```

The key to understanding the grouping is that a group is essentially a key/value collection where the key is what you group on and the value is a collection of all the items that met the group selector; the collection is what you can than work against for each group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393(v=vs.100).aspx) of `GroupBy` using a resultselector:

```
var result = tests.GroupBy(t => new { t.TestName, t.SampleSize },
            (k, v) => new 
            { 
               SampleSize = k.SampleSize, 
               TestName = k.TestName, 
               Average = v.Average(t => t.Result) 
            });
```

In `(k, v)` `k` is the key you grouped by and `v` are all the elements in each group.